# Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) Bluetooth Address Randomisation

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I am planning to code an application that has the capability of scanning advertising beacons around me and complete a BLE handshake with these beacons. (Basically central and peripheral functions). However,  I need the device's bdaddress (Bluetooth Address) to rotate after each scan as some of these advertising beacons have blacklisting functions which only allows my device to connect 1 time and subsequently not allowing the my device to reconnect again. I read that some contact tracing applications frequently rotate the device's identifier through identifier randomisation. Does anyone know how to achieve this?